# How can we set the border to a list item in list view

Tags: android

By Default in the `Listview`,focus will come on the list item.
Instead of that, can I get only the border to the list item?

I can achieve this by using a transparent image as a list selector.
Is there any other simplest way to achieve this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an [android:drawSelectorOnTop](http://developer.android.com/intl/zh-TW/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#attr_android:drawSelectorOnTop) XML property that might work for you.

> When set to true, the selector will be
>   drawn over the selected item.
>   Otherwise the selector is drawn behind
>   the selected item. The default value
>   is false.

I would also try if I can have a selector with drawables `"@null"`.